# How to test for conditions in multiple cells?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I need to test whether a cell has a certain value, but only if another cell is blank.

Example:

- If cell D34 has the value of "P" and K34 is blank return should be "1"
- If cell D34 has the value of "P" and K34 has any value Return should be "0"

Comment: Are you talking about two cells  or two columns?

Comment: What is supposed to result if D34 does not contain "P"?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
=COUNTIFS(D:D,"P",K:K,"")
```

[image]

Comment: @JackLink, glad it worked, please consider to mark your question as answered. Appreciate it

Comment: @JackLink, just be aware that this approach looks in the entire columns to return the result, not just the two cells you mentioned.  If there is other stuff going on anywhere else in those columns, it could return a different result that has nothing to do with the two cells you're interested in.